# Compressing Site prior to completion

Tags: compression, jquery

Should a sites development be completed prior to setting the compression for site and jquery? If so then what would happen if you then need to do maintenance of the site further down the track.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You should maintain the uncompressed version for development.
2. Use any tool to compress the javascript files automatically.
3. if Joomla debug mode is true, include un-compressed files, else include compressed files.

**Tip**

Checking  debug mode in joomla.

```
echo JDEBUG ? 'debug mode is on' : 'debug mode is off' ;
```

Comment: Is `JDEBUG` always _defined_?

Comment: Yes, as it is checked in index.php file. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/index.php#L34

Comment: Ok, that would seem to suggest that it is safe to assume that it is. In fact, it appears to be defined in `/includes/framework.php` which is included earlier in `index.php`. (My initial concern was that if `JDEBUG` is not defined then the above statement will evaluate to `true`, which is probably not correct. I encountered this sort of thing whilst debugging WordPress a while ago; hence my concern.)